# Google Vision API not able to detect numbers of large sizes in an image using Text_Detection Type(OCR).Why is it not working and some alternatives?

Tags: python-3.x, google-vision

[Google API was not able to detect anything in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrUGd.png)

Comment: Thank you.Its working well for ocr.space...dont know why its not working for google.